# How do I join/reduce a list of strings to a single string?

Tags: nix

I want to convert this

```
builtins.readFile ../../dotfiles/vim/commands.vim + "\n" +
builtins.readFile ../../dotfiles/vim/keybindings.vim + "\n" +
builtins.readFile ../../dotfiles/vim/plugins.vim
```

into something more dynamic. This is what I've got so far. It evaluates to a list of strings.

```
map
  ( fileName: builtins.readFile ( ../../dotfiles/vim + "/${fileName}" )
  ( builtins.AttrNames ( builtins.readDir ../../dotfiles/vim ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

With `lib.concatStrings`.

```
# Generic:
lib.concatStrings [ "a" "b" "c" ] # Returns "abc"

# Specific:

lib.concatStrings (
  ( map
    ( fileName: builtins.readFile ( ../../dotfiles/vim + "/${fileName}" )
    ( builtins.AttrNames ( builtins.readDir ../../dotfiles/vim ) )
  );
```

Comment: see [nixpkgs/lib/strings.nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/lib/strings.nix)